# Properties that a linear transformation preserves

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Why is it important to study which properties are preserved by a linear trasformation ?

In which ways can we practically use this knowledge ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice handout that should answer both your questions:

https://files.vipulnaik.com/math-196/geometryoflineartransformations.pdf